# How to use querycommands in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

In TinyMCE i am able to get the currently selected values by using queryCommandValue and queryCommandState like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.queryCommandValue("FontName");
```

This would get me the selected fontname. How would i do something like this in CKEditor?

Answer (score 1):

The command state can be checked using the following  available methods in CKEDITOR.command list.

## previousState

Indicates the previous command state.

```
alert( command.previousState );
```

## state

Indicates the editor state. Possible values are:

CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED: the command is disabled. It's execution will have no effect. Same as disable.
CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON: the command is enabled and currently active in the editor (for context sensitive commands, for example).
CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF: the command is enabled and currently inactive in the editor (for context sensitive commands, for example).

Do not set this property directly, this can also be achieved using the #setState method instead.

e.g

```
command.setState( CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON );
```

one can also check the state to do execute a command or to do some task

```
if ( command.state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED )
    alert( 'This command is disabled' );
```

queryCommandValue can be done while executing a normal command like `command.exec(data)` and this value of data should come from some variable in which this value is stored.

Comment: How would this enable me to get and set the font type f.x.?

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: The latest i think. 4.3

Comment: Ok it is EOD for today will let you know tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the document to perform direct DOM calls as you want by doing it this way

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.$.queryCommandValue("FontName")
```

but I must warn you that directly calling the DOM instead of using the CKEditor API is gonna be harder. CKEditor has been designed to wrap the differences between browsers, and if you want to skip that and use other API then you'll have to redo a lot of work.